# Uniform Circular motion and rate of change of Vectors related to it

Tags: rotational-kinematics

When I was studying uniform circular motion and thinking of ways to derive the expressions of related vectors like centripetal and centrifugal acceleration I noticed a certain oddity that occurred in my derivation. I want to know if it is simply a coincidence or whether there is some way to explain it.

Let us consider a circle of uniform radius $r$ with the $r$ making an angle of $\alpha$. Now let us consider two unit vectors $\vec e_r$ along the radial direction with the tail connected to the tip of the $r$ vector. Also the other is $\vec e_t$ where $\vec e_t$ is along the tangent of the circle.

Now we get on resolving them into the components;
$$\vec e_t = cos\alpha \hat j -sin\alpha \hat i$$
$$\vec e_r = cos \alpha \hat i + sin \alpha \hat j$$
$$ \vec r = \vert r \vert \cdot \vec e_r$$
Now differentiating w.r.t time, we can derive all off the expressions required however I noticed that the $\vec e_r$ when differentiated w.r.t angle $\alpha$ we get,
$$ \frac {d e_r}{d \alpha} = \vec e_t$$
Is this simply a coincidence or is there some sort of concept that can be unearthed here?

Also, can someone tell me someway I can create an image to make the figure clear?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this formula just reflects, in the vector form, a relationship between the length of an arc, the radius and the angle subtended by the arc: $S=r\theta$.

The diagram below, shows two unit radial vectors, $\vec e_r$ and $\vec e_r+d\vec e_r$, separated by a small angle $d\alpha$. It also shows a difference vector, $d\vec e_r$, pointing roughly in the direction of a unit tangent vector $\vec e_t$.

[image]

With respect to this diagram, your formula says that the magnitude of the difference vector, $d\vec e_r$, is equal to the product of the unit radius, $1$, and the angle $d\alpha$ ($S=r\theta$), while its direction coincides with the direction of the tangent vector $\vec e_t$, which is a good approximation for small angles.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent vector $\vec{T}(\alpha)$ for a curve parameterized by some parameter $\alpha$, say $\vec{r}(\alpha)$, is given by the derivative with respect to $\alpha$, $$\vec{T}(\alpha)\equiv\frac{d}{d\alpha}\vec{r}(\alpha).$$  Your radial unit vector $\hat{e}_r(\alpha)$ is just the unit length vector pointing to the point on the circle parameterized by $\alpha$, so it's natural that taking the $\alpha$ derivative of $\hat{e}_r$ gives you $\hat{e}_t$, the unit vector along the tangent to the circle.

Comment: Why is the tangent to the curve parameterized by some parameter $\alpha$ given by $\frac {d}{d \alpha}$ $\vec r (\alpha)$? Or is that a question for a mathematics forum?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform time derivative (and not derivative w.r.t. an angle), you can prove that

$\dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}} = \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf{\hat{e}}$,

being $\boldsymbol \omega$ the angular velocity of the moving unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{e}}$, and thus $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{\hat{e}}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{\hat{e}}$.

If you evaluate this in a 2D problem, where there is no ambiguity about the representation of rotations, for the unit vectors of a polar basis moving uniformly on a circle or radius $r$:

- the angular velocity reads $\boldsymbol \omega = \dot \alpha \mathbf{\hat{k}}$
- time deritvative of $\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r}$ reads

  $\dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r} = \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r} = \dot \alpha \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta} $,
- time deritvative of $\mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta}$ reads

  $\dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta} = \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta} = -\dot \alpha \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r} $

In order to get the derivative w.r.t. to the angle, we change the independent variable through chain rule in differentiation

$\dfrac{d}{d\alpha} \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r} = \dfrac{d t}{d\alpha} \dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{r} = \dfrac{1}{\dot \alpha} \dot \alpha \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta} = \mathbf{\hat{e}}_{\theta}$